# Formatting output in python

Tags: python, linux

This is my code:

```
import commands

mount = commands.getoutput('mount -v')
lines = mount.splitlines()
points = map(lambda line: line.split()[2], lines)
permission = map(lambda line: line.split()[5], lines)
print points
print permission
```

The output I am getting is:

```
['/', '/proc', '/sys', '/dev/pts', '/dev/shm', '/boot', '/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc', '/var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs']
['(rw)', '(rw)', '(rw)', '(rw,gid=5,mode=620)', '(rw,rootcontext="system_u:object_r:tmpfs_t:s0")', '(rw)', '(rw)', '(rw)']
```

I want to display permission of each partition in front of it. Like:

```
'/'        (rw)
'/proc'    (rw)
```

and so on. How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use zip function for this

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y = [4, 5, 6]
>>> zipped = zip(x, y)
>>> zipped
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

in your case

```
zipped = zip(points, permission)
for i, j in zipped:
    print i, j
```

for more details look [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)